# Simple login form in php md5?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, md5

I created a simple login form using php/Mysql and i am using md5 to store passwords

Given 1 as the password for registration as well as login

In registration form

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass']));
    echo $_POST['pass'];
    echo $pass;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, pass, email) VALUES ('$username', '$pass', '$email')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    if($result){
        $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
        echo $msg;
    }
}
?>
```

c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b

Whereas in login form on entering the same password

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
function SignIn()
{

echo "Session Started";
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page

$myuser  = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
$mypass = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['pass']));
echo "<br/>";
echo $myuser;
echo "<br/>";
echo $mypass;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$myuser'") or die(mysql_error());
echo $query;
echo "<br/>";
echo "After query";
echo "<br/>";
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query,  MYSQL_BOTH) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo $row[1];
echo "<br/>";
echo $row[2];
echo "<br/>";
echo "After fetching arrays";
echo "<br/>";
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $count;    


/*  if($count == 1)
{
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$myuser;
    header("location: welcome.php");
    echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";

}
else
{
    echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
}*/

}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
SignIn();
}
?>
```

but the md5 generated varies

da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd8070

Approaches given to my problem

Print the $_POST['pass'] directly

Don't use md5 for password related.

P.S. Now my code is working Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Please don't use md5 for hashing passwords, it's insecure and your site will be compromised.

Comment: provide code for your registraion form

Comment: Did you type the same password?

Comment: You don't need to escape the md5 value as it only contains 0-9a-f values. Try echo'ing or var_dumping the $_POST values before to see if it really is the same value.

Edit: as The Blue Dog said, don't use MD5. It isn't made for passwords. If you can, use bcrypt instead.

Comment: `c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b` = **`1`**

Comment: And your second hash (`da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd8070`) isn't valid, it **`39`** characters, and a MD5 hash is **`32`** characters.

Comment: On the last comment, your hash would be `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890` which, according to [this](http://www.md5this.com/list.php?page=1132&key=1&author=ToXiC&country=Cyprus&city=Nicosia) is still cracking and apparently an empty password [here](https://www.freerainbowtables.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2072&start=15). Which means : **Please don't use MD5(), look at password_hash() or blowfish instead! It is redundant and effectively useless as a hashing mechanism.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just cant be possible, try

```
echo $_POST['pass'];
```

before md5 to check if value is the same, maybe you are getting wrong string

Comment: That would've been better as a comment.

Comment: yes if I have had permission to post comments, please remove that -1 from me since I don-t have enough points to post comments

Comment: In this case it would help if you just explain your approach in more detail. What does it do to help with the problem, what is a possible outcome and what should be done in regards to the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use SHA256, and if you do have the password inside the database set to SHA256 (which can be easily done); you can check it as follows: `hash('sha256',$_POST['pass'])`, and you can save it in the database: `sha256('test')`.

You can insert it via: `hash('sha256',$_POST['pass'])`

and check it in the same manner; simple checking:

```
SELECT * FROM tblLoginExample WHERE loginPassword = '" . hash('sha256',$_POST['Pass']) . "' WHERE loginUsername = '" . $_POST['User'] . "'";
```

Hope this helps you build the desired functionality.